# How to calculate remaining height even when overflow scroll stops. [JQUERY]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a custom scrollbar behavior of a div that goes down based on calculated; height of parent and current position scrollTop.

However, when the content reaches the end, the div stays in the middle and does not go beyond the `top: 100%` (actually it's 85 to be precise) How can I calculate that the div actually goes to the bottom?

```
$('.carousel-items').scroll(function() {
  var currY = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(currY);

  var postHeight = $(this).height();
  var scrollHeight = $('.carousel-item').height();
  var scrollPercent = (currY / (scrollHeight - postHeight)) * 100;

  scrollPercent = Math.abs(scrollPercent);

  $('.test').css('top', scrollPercent +"%"  );

});
```

I tried multiplying the sum by 1000 instead of 100, but the items in the content are dynamically added. I am now in a test environment (experimenting with 4 items) but when the project finishes the items in it could be like 20..

As you can see in the image, the scrollbar is reaches the end but the blue T div stays at the middle.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YraYi.png)